# Word-request to express "teaching only one person"

Tags: word-request

I have some experience in teaching kids that have difficulty at school and I helped them with lesson where the student was alone with me. How can I express this activity?

Can we say one-to-one teaching, personal teaching, private teaching, one-student teaching,..?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would typically call this tutoring. As the instructor, you would be the tutor. The recipient of tutoring is still a student.